# Strange behaviour of angular bootstrap collapse

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I faced with strange behaviour of uib-collapse.
Let's assume I have a list of elements and i want each of them to be collapsed. Also i want to refresh its content periodically depend on something.

**For example:** i have some items and each of them have description which consists of some sections. I can pick item and description sections should be populated with item's description content. The problem is that each time i refresh its content, some sections are collapsing (despite the fact i set uib-collapse to *false*)

My controller:

```
var i = 0;
$scope.sections = [0,1,2];
$scope.next = function(nextOffset) {
    i+=nextOffset;
    $scope.sections = [i, i+1, i+2]
}
```

My template:

```
<button ng-click="next(1)" style="margin-bottom: 10px">Next item</button>
<button ng-click="next(2)" style="margin-bottom: 10px">Next next item</button>
<button ng-click="next(3)" style="margin-bottom: 10px">Next next next item</button>

<div ng-repeat="section in sections">
  <div uib-collapse="false">
    <div class="well well-lg">{{ section }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So when i click first button, only one section does transition. When i click second, 2 section do transition and click to third button leads to all section transition.

[See plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MEclpjtf4YqH2Pqc7Jqe?p=preview)

Any ideas?

**UPD:** if *$scope.sections* is array of object, not of primitives, then all sections have transition in each of 3 cases. It is so ugly...

Comment: I can't reproduce your error on your plunkr

Comment: There are no errors. It is strange that collapsing/expanding calls sometimes despite the fact that uib-collapse is constantly _false_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not refreshing the existing content, you are adding new arrays each time, which will make `ng-repeat` remove the old DOM elements and insert new ones.

If you try with `track by $index` you will see the difference:

```
<div ng-repeat="section in primitiveSections track by $index">
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/hTsVBrRLa8nWXhaqfhVK?p=preview

Note that `track by $index` might not be the solution you want in your real application, I just used it for demonstration purposes.

What you probably need is to just modify the existing objects in the array.

For example:

```
$scope.nextObject = function(nextOffset) {

  j += nextOffset;

  $scope.objectSections.forEach(function (o, i) {
    o.content = j + i;
  });
};
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/STxy1lAUGnyxmKL7jYJH?p=preview

---

### Update

From the collapse source code:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.uibCollapse, function(shouldCollapse) {
  if (shouldCollapse) {
    collapse();
  } else {
    expand();
  }
});
```

When a new item is added the watch listener will execute, `shouldCollapse` will always be false in your case so it will execute the `expand` function.

The `expand` function will always perform the animation:

```
function expand() {
  element.removeClass('collapse')
    .addClass('collapsing')
    .attr('aria-expanded', true)
    .attr('aria-hidden', false);

  if ($animateCss) {
    $animateCss(element, {
      addClass: 'in',
      easing: 'ease',
      to: {
        height: element[0].scrollHeight + 'px'
      }
    }).start().finally(expandDone);
  } else {
    $animate.addClass(element, 'in', {
      to: {
        height: element[0].scrollHeight + 'px'
      }
    }).then(expandDone);
  }
}
```

If this is the intended behavior or not I don't know, but this is the reason why it happens.

Comment: Thank you for reply, you are right! But why it animates at all if i pick different objects? See plunkr:        http://plnkr.co/edit/rP1AlbLsi1qXuJOJL0D6?p=preview
As i understand, it works with scope.$watch mechanism on uib-collapse attribute, but is doesn't change!

Comment: You're welcome :) I will need to have a look at the source code of angular-ui to see if it's intended or not. I will update if I find anything.

Comment: @CodeMed I see that someone has answered your question already. Let me know if the answer doesn't help you and I will take a look.

Comment: @tasseKATT Thank you very much.  I was actually able to resolve the other problem, but your availability is very much appreciated.

Comment: @CodeMen I will take a look in a while when I have time :)

Answer (score 0):

this is a comment on the original ui-bootstrap library: (and the new uib prefixed directive doesn't comply this comment.)

> // IMPORTANT: The height must be set before adding "collapsing" class.
>   Otherwise, the browser attempts to animate from height 0 (in 
>   collapsing class) to the given height here.

use the deprecated "collapse" directive instead of new "uib-collapse" until it gets fixed.