# angular bootstrap accordion collapses after data change

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ui.bootstrap

I'm using ui.bootstrap.accordion and experiencing an issue when data inside uib-accordion-group changes the group gets collapsed.  I'm not sure why this is happening.  Is there something specific i need to look out for ?

thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666761/strange-behaviour-of-angular-bootstrap-collapse

Comment: thank you so much - that worked !!